# Swapping out an object for one that already exists before save

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible when using Parse to have a `beforeSave` cloud function that will not just modify the object being saved but swap it out for an entirely new one.

Example...

I'm creating a messaging app that uses custom emojis as part of the message.

The images for the emojis are all stored locally on the device (along side a plist to reference them).

So, I have a `Message` table in Parse with an array of pointers to an `Emoji` table.

The `Emoji` table just has an `imageName` entry so that all I'm storing is enough data to be able to display the same image on all devices. I didn't want to have to be uploading and downloading hundreds of images.

So, the problem I have now is that if 15 different people all create messages with a "Smiley Face" emoji then I have 15 "Smiley Face" `Emoji` objects in the table but they're all essentially the same.

What I'd like to do is have a cloud code `before save` function that will look at the emoji and find one that is identical. If it doesn't find open then thats fine as it will just create a new one but if it does then it should use the existing one instead of creating a duplicate.

When I create the message I do it all in one save. I create the `message` object and add the array of `emoji` objects and then run a background save on the `message` (which also saves the children).

I haven't got any code yet as I am really not a JS developer so I didn't want to just start hacking away. Would be nice to get some guidance though.

Comment: Are you creating new rows in the Emoji table or just pointers to existing rows when you save Message? If so, what's unique about those records?

Comment: @RyanDuffy Creating new rows. Only because I don't want to have to download them all because it isn't needed. I've actually been thinking about dropping the table and "encoding" the array in text instead. The unique field(s) is actually a combination. The `type` field plus either `imageName`, `user` (pointer to PFUser), or `date`

Comment: Enconding them in text might be a simpler solution. It doesn't sound like you need to maintain the relationship between a Message and an Emoji in Parse but I'm sure you didn't share all your requirments in your post. I'll attempt to answer your question and see where that goes. :)

Comment: @RyanDuffy Thanks, I think you're right. And yes, I don't really need it as a relationship. Encoding it in text was actually what I did in the first place and then changed to this way. I think it's probably wiser to stay with my initial idea of text encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "redirect" an object in `beforeSave` such that I'm trying to save an object and instead *silently* update another. You could update another object during beforeSave but to prevent saving the new one, you'd have to fail that operation which doesn't sound like what you wanted to do.

You could add a `beforeSave` hook to `Message` to update the pointers to `Emoji`. In your case, however, this wouldn't prevent the new records in `Emoji` from being created because those have to be created first in order to create the pointers from `Message`.

If you truly needed the pointers in Parse from a `Message` to the `Emoji`s used **and** you only wanted one record for each `Emoji` in the system, you could either:

- Retrieve all the `Emoji` records at start-up (and possibly cache them locally) and the add them as pointers when you create a new Message
- Use a cloud code function to create messages in which you look up the `Emoji` based upon parameters or the content of the message

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That second option sounds interesting. I hadn't even thought about doing something like that. For now I'm going to go back to my text encoding system. But I'll keep that second option in mind for the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMO your message table entries can use a pointer ( to one or to many parse files ).

details on each pointer...

```
{"toEmoji":{"__type":"File","name":"9d74eb8e-11bd-4bd0-9146-bc01c6656daa-......jpg","url":"http://files.parse.com/09d82830-ec2d-40b4-bb14-944728550685/9d74eb8e-11bd-4bd0-9146-bc01c6656daa-.......jpg"}}
```

So, before POST action on any file to upload a new emoji, run your process to find existing DUPE.

The onDupe() can just return the same signature that a File POST to parse returns... 
  ie {"fileName": "", "fileUrl": "" }

and then its kinda independent ( does not know if attribute values being used as target of new message pointer are to an existing file or to a new file ).

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of doing something like that. I'll definitely consider it.